# Can not run a jar file programatically through a web service

Tags: java, spring, jar

Something strange happens when I try running a `java -jar` command programatically on Windows.

When running the command like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd); //cmd string is ok
p.waitFor();
```

I get the error

> Error: Could not find or load main class �jar

However, when I'm trying to run it like this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("hard coded command with parameters"); 
p.waitFor();
```

in this case, it works fine.

The cmd string is generated using `String.Format` which receives its parameters throug a Spring web service:

```
cmd = String.format("java –jar %s –o win -i %s -n %s -d %s -s %s", jarLocation, param1, param2, tgtFilePath, srcFilePath);
```

I suspect the issue is related somehow to the parameter's encoding.
Is there a way to make sure? Can I somehow change the string's encoding as I receive it through the web service? I'm testing the web service on Windows but eventually it will probably sit on a Solaris station if it matters.

Comment: Show us the code for the cmd variable.

Comment: What are the values of the parameters when it fails? (especially jarLocation).

Comment: @StephaneM all the values are correct. The generated string is correct as well. The specific parameter of the location is simply the file name since I assume I have the jar file at the same folder as the web service.  Like I wrote, if I replace the cmd var with the exact same command, only hard coded, everything works.

Comment: If everything was correct it would work, don't you think? Sometimes it's so obvious that you just can't see. Just read this this morning: http://www.commitstrip.com/en/2015/10/07/when-your-colleagues-are-stuck-on-a-something-simple/?setLocale=1 :)

Comment: The strings values ARE correct. like I said, when hard coding the exact same string to the code, everything works. That is why I believe it might be some encoding issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking at the bytes of the two string I found that for some reason, the `String.Format` might generate the '-' characters as an en-dash (format string contains U+2013) instead of hyphen (U+002D). I'm not sure why it did that but I copy pasted an hyphen to the formatted String and then everything worked.